# CoreData does not update all relationships properly

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have two entities in CoreData Todo and DaysOfYear and a many to one relationship exists between these two entities. When the user launches the app if for the past 4 days the user has not completed any of the todos I add those todos to the `incompleteTodos` relationship for each day. Thing is only the first day gets updated in core data while the rest of them do not update. I have tried everything that I could, all to no avail. Core Data simply refuses to store any of the updates I make except for the first day even though context.hasChanges acknowledges that the context has changed.

[image]

ContentView from where I add IncompleteTodos:

```
Todo.addIncompleteTodo(todo: todo, for: days[idx].date, context: context)
```

Extension Todo:

```
static func addIncompleteTodo(todo: Todo, for day: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    let today = DayOfYear.withDate(convertStringToGMTDate(day), context: context)
    todo.incompleteDay = today
    today.addToIncompleteTodos_(todo)
    print(context.hasChanges)
    try? context.save()
}
```

Extension DayOfYear:

```
static func withDate(_ day: Date, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> DayOfYear {
    let request = fetchRequest(NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@ AND date <= %@", day.startOfDay() as CVarArg, day.endOfDay() as CVarArg))
    let days = (try? context.fetch(request)) ?? []
    if let day = days.first {
        return day
    } else {
        let newDay = DayOfYear(context: context)
        var newDate: Date
        let secondsFromGMT = TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT()
        if secondsFromGMT > 0 {
            newDate = day.endOfDay()
        } else if secondsFromGMT < 0 {
            newDate = day.startOfDay()
        } else {
            newDate = day
        }
        newDay.date = newDate
        return newDay
    }
}

static func fetchRequest(_ predicate: NSPredicate) -> NSFetchRequest<DayOfYear> {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<DaysOfYear>(entityName: "DaysOfYear")
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)]
    request.predicate = predicate
    return request
}
```

So let's say if I add 4 incompleteTodos for 10th, 9th, 8th and 7th September 2020. Core Data would only update the relationship for 7th September and store 4 incompleteTodos while 8th, 9th, 10th Septmeber will show 0 incompleteTodos after running this code. If I add a new Todo on the 10th, it will immediately be reflected in incompleteTodos for the 10th, but will NOT update incompleteTodos for 11th September.

Comment: Well you are always returning the first found day here:
let days = (try? context.fetch(request)) ?? []
    if let day = days.first {
        return day
    }

Comment: Yes if the particular day which I am searching in CD already exists, I return that day. If that day does not exist, then I create a new day in the else clause and return that. Its working fine up til here and I can see the correct dates before I assign a todo to that particular day.

Comment: You don't need that relationship, just add a Date attribute to your ToDo entity and then you can use a NSPredicate to find all ToDo's for a given date.

Comment: I have many more fields in DaysOfYear. For brevity I only showed the relevant ones. The problem was that the cardinality should not have been a One To Many rather it should have been a Many to Many. Because it was a One To Many, CD only stored the last data that was entered and obviously overwrote the previous ones.